Vscode devcontainers: is there something like 'global' extensions?
Ive been using vscode and devcontainers for a while now, and i really like the workflow.having specific extensions indtalled, based on a specific environment is great, especially because i need to use a lot of different environment on a regular basis (python, vanilla js/ts, react, angular, c#,...).
Last week I started playing around with ollama, and installed the 'continue' extension for using the ollama model as a coding assistant.
However, when I open a devcontainer, the continue extension cant find the models installed on the host machine (makes sense).
Is there anyway to have an extension installed with some kind of 'global' modifier, or have it access data from the host machine?
